# Java SSH connection

Tags: java, mysql, ssh

How can I connect to internet server from Java desktop application? I need to access MySQL database and upload/download files. The host that I have (one.com), don't support remote database access, so I've tried with SSH. I don't know anything at all about this. I've tried various codes examples but none of them pass further than connection. I add jsch.jar to my project. Is there something else that I have to add/install or what em I missing?

```
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    String user = "user";
    String password = "pass";
    String host = "00.000.00.000";
    int port=22;

String remoteFile="/home/mywebsite.com/test.txt";

try
    {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = (Session) jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
    session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connection established.");
    System.out.println("Creating SFTP Channel.");
    ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
    sftpChannel.connect();
    System.out.println("SFTP Channel created.");


    InputStream out= null;
    out= sftpChannel.get(remoteFile);
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(out)))     {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(line);
    }
    }
catch(JSchException | SftpException | IOException e){System.err.print(e);}
}
```

I get the error:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 24 seconds)
```

Or what other alternatives I have to achieve a remote connection to my site & database?

**P.S.** I have tried almost all the example-codes from stackoverflow and all get stuck in the same point ...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Connection timed out` indicates that you're trying to connect to a server that isn't accepting SSH connections on port 22, or your host is incorrect. Is `host = "00.000.00.000";` the actual IP address you're trying to connect to, or did you change it for your Stack Overflow question?

Comment: That isn't my real IPaddress ... I've change it, like the user and password for obvious reasons... :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to debug your code, but will tell you how to accomplish this.

The solution is to use SSH "port forwarding", which you should first set up from the command line, to learn how it works, before embedding it in your Java code.  You may not need to write any code if a command-line tunnel will suffice.

```
ssh -L3306:localhost:3306 <databaseHost>
```

This creates an SSH "tunnel" from your computer's port 3306 to the `<databaseHost>` and then on to `localhost` from `<databaseHost>`.  Any connection on your computer to your local port 3306 gets tunnelled across SSH to `<databaseHost>` and then on to whatever `<databaseHost>` knows as `localHost`, i.e. back to itself, on port 3306.

When your Java code connects to the database, it should connect to `localhost:3306`.  Note that the `localhost` in your database connect string refers to your computer, while the one in the `ssh` command is from the point of view of the remote server, so they mean different things.

In summary, a packet from your Java code to the remote MySQL server travels the following route:

```
Connect to my computer port 3306
Intercepted by ssh
Encrypted and transmitted to remote database server
Decrypted by sshd and fed to port 3306 on the same server
Received by MySQL running on the remote host
```

For return packets, this process is reversed, managed by the local ssh client and the remote sshd daemon.

Note that this can be used for more interesting cases. For example, suppose the remote ssh server and database server are on different systems behind the same firewall.  Let's say the ssh host is visible as gateway.xyz.com, while the database host is on an internal LAN at 10.0.0.3 which is not reachable from the Internet, but reachable from the gateway.

```
ssh -L3306:10.0.0.3:3306 gateway.xyz.com
```

The packet route is then

```
Your computer 3306
Received by ssh
Encryption and sent to gateway.xyz.com
Decrypted by sshd forwarded to 10.0.0.3:3306
Received at 10.0.0.3:3306 by MySQL
```

To be clear, this is something you set up from the command line, before executing your Java code, which should happen in a different session from the ssh command.  The tunnel remains available as long as the ssh command is running.